# Solr conditional update

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I want to know if there is some way to do a conditional update in Solr.

Our documents are coming from multiple channels reading source-of-truth DB and it is possible that a later version of document gets indexed first (because the channel corresponding to that version somehow got more priority and succeeded in doing the update).

The *version* field is maintained in the DB.
So we cannot really make use of *version* field in Solr (because Solr expects it to match exactly  believing that the document was read from Solr too).

What I want is something like this:

```
Update SolrDoc if SolrDoc.version > IndexedDoc.version
```

It would be great if UpdateRequest provided a query parameter to do the same or something similar.
At this point, I see no other way out other than to use UpdateRequestProcessor but the documentation on that is severely lacking and I cannot figure out where to place the java code written in custom UpdateRequestProcessor

Comment: http://heliosearch.org/solr/optimistic-concurrency/

Comment: Mauricio, I told in my requirement that I cannot use _version_ because my requirement is slightly different.
The link you gave has the semantics "Update where version = <older-version>" where as I want "Update where version >= <old-version>" This will ensure that even if one channel updates with two versions older than current version it should update well.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that!